# Align the Text in the Center of the banner

Tags: html, css

I have made a banner which is shown on the Internet Explorer for my web-app, but the text inside isn't  being aligned to the center. You can refer the Image below.

What is the mistake in my Code?
[image]

below is the code for the Banner and also its CSS is mentioned below.

HTML Code:

```
<div class="banner" id="banner_strip">
    <span class="header-font">Recommended to use Chrome, Firefox or Microsoft Edge for better performance and security</span>
    <button class="close-button" id="close_button" onclick="closeBanner()">X</button>
</div>
```

The CSS Code :

```
@media all and (-ms-high-contrast: none), (-ms-high-contrast: active) {
    /* IE10+ CSS styles go here */
     .banner {
        visibility: visible ;
        background-color: azure;
        padding-top: initial;
        text-align: center;
        height: 40px;
    }
    .header-font {
        padding-top: 2px;
        padding-bottom: 2px;
        font-size: 20px;
    }
    
    .close-button {
        text-align: right;
        font-size: 10px;
        background: none;
        border: none;
        
    }
}
```

Comment: It most likely involves the margins of your div with class "banner". If you set margin-left and margin-right on .banner to auto it may solve the issue, but it will be dependent on the styling of the parent element of the div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with add text-align center to span class

```
 .header-font {
    padding-top: 2px;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try following CSS if any query let me know.

```css
.banner {
   visibility: visible ;
   background-color: azure;
   padding-top: initial;
   text-align: center;
   height: 40px;
   display: inline-block;
   width: 100%;
}

.header-font {
   padding-top: 2px;
   padding-bottom: 2px;
   font-size: 20px;
   text-align: center;
}
```